# CSS/HTML logic for making 4 divs each take up 1/4 of the space and have 1-pixel overlapping borders

Tags: html, css

Here's what my test page looks like now: http://jaminweb.com/boardBeta.php

What I'd like for that table (created with divs ... Don't worry; I'm not using `table`) is to have the 4 colums each equally spaced and with overlapping borders of 1 white pixel (meaning there's exactly 1 white pixel separating them horizontally .. I understand that setting their `borders` each to `1px` will make 2 pixels separate them) and taking up the entire width of the divs in which they reside.

My CSS:

```
div.threadsrow:nth-of-type(2n+0)
{
    background-color: #ccc;  
}

div.threadsrow:nth-of-type(2n+1)
{
    background-color: #F9C624;    
}

div#threads
{
    width: 100%;  
    border: 5px solid #333;
    padding: 0px;
}

div.threadscol
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 24%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My HTML:

```
    <div id="threads">
        <div class="threadsrow">
            <div class="threadscol"><p><b>Title</b></p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p><b>Creator</b></p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p><b>Last Post Time/Date</b></p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p><b>Number of Posts</b></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="threadsrow">
            <div class="threadscol"><p>Foo</p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p>Joe</p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p>11:49/4/16/2013</p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p>0</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="threadsrow">
            <div class="threadscol"><p>Bar</p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p>Jack</p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p>11:34/4/16/2013</p></div>
            <div class="threadscol"><p>0</p></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

When I change the `width` to `25%`, the columns get pushed onto the next line. I understand this is because of the border, but it happens even when I change the `border` to `0px`. So I'm not what is going on here.

I know this sounds pathetic, but I've been an entry-level web developer for 2 months and I still get confused about the logic of HTML and CSS. I'm finding it extremely frustrating lol.

Can someone please explain the logic of how to accomplish the format I desire?

Comment: There are top-level web developers who don't know how positioning works, so I would plan on being confused often - and indefinitely. This should actually be a table probably. No real reason to have these as inline-block, and should definitely get box-sizing involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your cells are inline-block elements, they're sensitive to white space, and that's causing part of the problem. So remove the excess white space, and then add the `box-sizing:border-box` rule to your `div.threadscol` divs. Setting the box-sizing to border-box allows the padding and border to be included in the 25% width calculation.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c42Rr/)**

Also, one alternative to removing the white space is to set the font size on the parent to zero, and then increase it for the cell data.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M2m2G/)

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue with white-space using display of inline-block. If you add `white-space: nowrap;` to `div#threads` this will fix your issue. Then you can also add `margin: -5px` (your border is 5px) to the same element to prevent the border from being "off-the-page" on the right side.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/c42Rr/2/)

```
div#threads {
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    margin: -5px;
    padding: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table approach. At the very least, you probably want your "lists" of posts in lists if not a table. It depends what CMS is spitting out your info. If you are new to this, I would encourage you to start off on the right foot and think of how this is going to look on a phone. Stackoverflow has a nice phone version.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/rCVQK/)

### HTML

```
<div class="table-w">

    <table class="your-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Creator</th>
            <th>Last Post Time/Date</th>
            <th>Number of Posts</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>11:49/4/16/2013</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>Bar</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>11:34/4/16/2013</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>          
    </table>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.table-w {
    border: 3px solid black
}

.your-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.your-table th {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #F9C624;
}

.your-table th, .your-table td {
    width: 25%;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.row {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #F9C624; 
}
```